# React native setState with multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, setstate

I'm defining my state in constructor like this.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    order: props.data ? { ...props.data } : { title: '', birthdate: '' , gender: '', startdate: '', starttime: '', brand: null},
```

Then in another function i'm trying to setState only for order.brand

```
  this.setState({
    //order: { brand: items[0].title },
    order: { ...order, brand: items[0].title },
  });
```

The commented line is overwriting all elements, and the second returns that order is not defined.

What's the correct syntax to save just one item of the state that have multiple values.

Comment: Have you tried assigning state or using [`update`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `update` to modify object values:

```
var update = require('react-addons-update');

this.setState(function(previousState, currentProps) {
    var newState = update(previousState,{
        order: {
            brand: {
                $set: 'some new value'
            }
        }
    });

    return newState;
});
```

see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Comment: Unexpected token on order {

Answer (score 0):

Just to note why that error exists, it's possible that order is actually undefined where you are using it.

You're liking trying to use `{...this.state.order}`